# CSS selecting chart in svg tag

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following html structure

```
   <div class="_container">
      <div id="chart-3" class="chart with-3d-shadow with-transitions">
          <svg class=".svg">
              <text class="nvd3 nv-noData" >No Data Available.</text>
      </svg>
   </div>
```

I've tried checking if the "nv-noData exists" using the following but can't seem to get it to work:

```
        if ($('._container > .chart > .svg > .nv-noData').length > 0) { 
            alert("No Data!");  
        }
```

However, the following does throw an alert:

```
        if ($('._container > .chart > .svg > nv-noData').length > 0) { 
            alert("No Data!");  
        }
```

Being new to CSS, an explanation of why would be helpful to.

Also, if I removed the `class = ".svg"`, how would the CSS change?

Comment: You shouldn't put the dot in the attribute.  So it'd be `<svg class="svg">`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zY9FX/

Comment: Please make sure that jQuery/JS will support all your future tasks. Embedded SVG can become really nasty in that regard which is why most of the time you want to use additional libraries like raphaelJS. I'm not saying it's bad, but be aware that you could encounter big problems at a later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are *selected* via `.classname`, but *defined* via `class="classname"`. So in your example, your class name should be:

```
<svg class="svg">
    <text class="nvd3 nv-noData" >No Data Available.</text>
</svg>
```

and it would be selected via:

```
$('._container > .chart > .svg > .nv-noData')
```

This also has a dot before the `.nv-noData` selector, since you're selecting a class here.

---

Alternatively, you can omit the class tag altogether, and just use:

```
$('._container > .chart > svg > .nv-noData')
```

notice that I didn't put a `.` in front of the svg selector. This causes the selector to select `svg` tags instead of classes. This would then also work without the class:

```
<svg>
    <text class="nvd3 nv-noData" >No Data Available.</text>
</svg>
```

So in summary: If you select something with a dot in front of it, it will select a class name, and if you select it without dot in front of it, it will select the tag name. [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) also lists most other selectors there are, and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) is the official reference

Comment: should .nv-noData have a dot?

Comment: @user1357015 oh yeah I didn't even notice that >_< let me fix that :P. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: hm, still confused, for some reason it's not working.

Comment: @user1357015 could you post your whole code on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.org so I can have a look at what might be going wrong? Keep in mind that the HTML code (the `svg` tag) is not the full code - you still need the `div` tags around it for the selector to work.

Comment: ack you're right.. the ajax code modifies the page a split second after alert. So while it "would" work if the page was already complete, it doesn't in this case since it hasn't full loaded... I'll mark this as solved though as you did answer my problem. Thanks!